# Sending variable from Controller to view through route

Tags: php, laravel

I want to send data from a logincontroller to routes/web.php.

In my LoginController.php I have

```
return redirect()
        ->intended('/dashboard')
        ->with([
            'name'=>'Joe Steel',
            'address'=>'Blk 4, Bryton street',
            'gender'=>'male',
            ]);//this is the data I want to send
```

in my routes/web.php I have

```
Route::get('/dashboard', function(){
        //from session
    $names = Session::get('name');//extract name from session
    $address = Session::get('address');//extract name from session
    
    return View::make('view/directory/dashboard', [
        'name'=>$names, 
        'address'=>$address]);
                    //load web view , 
                    //send name which would be displayed in 
                    //dashboard.blade.php {{$name}} and {{$address}}
});
```

in my dashboard.blade.php I have

```
{{$name}} and {{$address}}
```

This is producing no output. i.e. the location where they where meant to show up in is empty

When I do not give View::make() any variable identifier e.g. View::make('dashboard',[$names,$address])
It produces error
Undefined variable: name (View: /laravel/installed/directory.php)

So I do not know if the route/web.php is receiving anything from the controller and I am also confused on how to pass it to the view through the array.

Please what could be the reason why this is happening

**update**

I noticed that the session was not being passed from my controller, I do not know what could be the reason for this. Is there something that I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

with() method accepts key array as first value and values itself as second, so try
to chain with method like this, instead of calling it one time.

```
return redirect()
    ->intended('/dashboard')
    ->with('name', 'Joe Steel')
    ->with('address', 'Blk 4, Bryton street')
    ->with('gender', 'male');
```

Please try to add dafault values to session data extraction.

```
$names = Session::get('name', 'default name');//extract name from session
$address = Session::get('address', 'default address');//extract name from session
```

And use relevant view path, instead of actual - project root one.

```
return view('directory.dashboard', [
    'name'=>$names, 
    'address'=>$address]);
```

using . instead of / in from resource folder in you'r path.

Plus, you can use Auth facade like

```
Auth::user();
```

to get you'r user data after he is logged in.

Comment: Passing a single associative array to `with()` is perfectly valid syntax as well; `->with(['one' => 'one', 'two' => 'two'])`, `->with('one', 'one')->with('two', 'two')` will do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Are you accessing the route `/dashboard` directly, or refreshing the page once you have been directed? Session data only persists for a single request. So if your `login` is successful and are redirected to `/dashboard`, the data will be available in the `session`. If you refresh the page or navigate away then return that data will no longer be available and so not display.

**Update**

When your `user` is successfully authenticated, you redirect your `user` to the `/dashboard` route with the `name` and `address` data you have added using `with(...)`.

You then get your `name` and `address` data from the `session` and pass that data to your view. The `name` and `address` will be available in the view the first time the user visits `/dashboard` as it was sent through from your `route` which got the data from your `session`. If the `user` goes to another page (`/dashboard/users` for example) and then goes back to `/dashboard`, the `name` and `address` data will not be available and will therefore not show. To get the `name` and `address` to show when the `user` goes to another page and back again, you'll need to set the `name` and `address` or just use [`Auth::user()->name;`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authentication#retrieving-the-authenticated-user) to get the name of the authenticated user.

Comment: Thanks, I am a little confused. Please can u shed more light on it. Please look at the update!!!

Comment: @SMev I have added some more detail to my answer which will hopefully better explain what I mean.